# multiple use of KCPSM3 (picoBlaze)

Tags: vhdl, picoblaze

I am currently working on a project that has to incorporate more than one picoBlaze. I am very new to the world of VHDL so I would like to ask you a question.

I created a new project and added source "KCPSM3.vhd". Then I created a top level entity that is supposed to use 2 picoBlazes. I've added the first picoBlaze component and it's corresponding program_rom and I set up the signals but now I am confused how to add another picoBlaze component.

Thanks.

Comment: Just instantiate another PicoBlaze. You can have as many PBs as fit onto your FPGA. The question is, do you really need multiple PBs or do you need a bigger instruction ROM?

Comment: How do I do it? Do I have to add another component to the achitecture?

Comment: What I want to do is connect switches on my FPGA to the Input port of first picoBlaze and then output it to the input port of next picoBlaze and output the data to the LEDs on my FPGA. I have to use 2 picoBlazes but I don't really know how to do it. If I declared my first picoBlaze component and it's program rom in my top_level entity architecture and then set up the signals for it, what is the next step to add second picoBlaze?

Comment: At first you need to learn VHDL. based on your question, you seem to have no knowledge about the hardware description language you're using. First you need to learn the language before you try to use it in real world designs. If you couple two PBs, you should use a FIFO in between. This is called a mailbox communication.